# Sum of product of two binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I wanted to find the value of the following expression

> $$\sum_{r=0}^{20} (-1)^r.  \binom {30}{r}. \binom {30}{r+10}$$

The Vandermonde's identity could have been used in this problem but the $(-1)^r$ makes it of no use. Using the binomial expansion and some brute force I got the answer as the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion $(1-x^2)^{30}$. But I am not able to provide the proof in writing because it was just by brute force and some observation.  Can someone please provide a hint.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives the answer immediately:  $30045015$.  What do you mean "closed form" in this context?

Comment: @David G. Stork I want a written mathematical proof for my obtained answer not just the expansion of $\binom {30}{10}$. Also typo fixed.

Comment: What about writing two terms, one for all the $(-1)^{+1}$ cases, and one for all the $(-1)^{-1}$ cases, use identities, and then subtract the results?  Hint:  $2095922267925255 - 2095922237880240 = 30045015$

Comment: Hint: consider the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(1-x)^{30}(1+x)^{30}$.

Comment: @Greg Martin how did you arrive at that result.  Because somewhere in my roughwork I saw that coming but now I don't remember how I got that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is convenient  to use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of  $z^n$  in  a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{20}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^r \binom {30}{r} \binom {30}{r+10}}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{20}(-1)^r \binom {30}{30-r} \binom {30}{r+10}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r\geq 0}[z^{30-r}](1-z)^{30}[u^{r+10}](1+u)^{30}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^{30}](1-z)^{30}\sum_{r\geq 0}z^r[u^r]u^{-10}(1+u)^{30}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^{30}](1-z)^{30}z^{-10}(1+z)^{30}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^{40}](1-z^2)^{30}\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{40}]\sum_{k=0}^{30}\binom{30}{k}(-1)^kz^{2k}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{30}{20}=30\,045\,015}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also set the upper limit to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (3) we  use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u=z$
  \begin{align*}
  A(z)=\sum_{r\geq0} a_r z^r=\sum_{r\geq 0} z^r  [u^r]A(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do some simplifications and apply the same rule as we did in (3).
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $z^{40}$.